# Apache mod_rewrite url rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I want to rewrite an url with mod_rewrite from http://www.server.com/directory/public to http://www.server.com/directory (where directory would be then directing to directory/public)

I've tried several things but I can't figure it out. Here is my configuration:

```
    <VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@server.com
            ServerName www.server.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www/server.com

        <Directory /var/www/server.com>
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/directory
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directory/public/ [L]
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your rewrite rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^/directory(.*) /directory/public$1 [NC,L]
```

You do not need the RewriteCond

Comment: Worked flawlessly! Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Within a `<Directory >` context, URIs in rewrite rules do not start with a `/`.

This is also true for URIs in rewrite rules in `.htaccess` files because they are implicitly in a directory.

The relevant part of the documentation is titled "[Per-directory Rewrites](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)"

To fix this you can do one of:

1. Move the RewriteRule and RewriteCond out of the `<Directory >` block.
2. Remove the leading slash from the RewriteCond and the second part of the RewriteRule.
3. Follow Ivmisooners' suggestion but also move the RewriteRule out of the `<Directory >` block.
4. Follow Ivmisooners' suggestion but remove the leading slashes from the RewriteRule.

If it were my choice, I would use option 3.

---

From my reading of the documentation page linked above, it seems to suggest that you must have `Options FollowSymLinks` enabled for RewriteRules to work in a per-directory context.  I have never tested this myself.  If you have troubles getting RewriteRules to work at all inside that `<Directory >` block, try adding `Options +FollowSymLinks`.